# MySQL merge multiple date columns into one

Tags: mysql, datetime, merge, concatenation

Ok so I have multiple datetime columns for things such as date_created, last_login, last_updated, etc... I would like to merge them into one column with the most recent datetime showing, so that I can track active_users more easily.

I've found some suggestions to use the CONCAT command, but that looks to be just stringing all the results together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT username, 
       GREATEST(date_created, last_login, last_updated) last_activity
FROM your_table
ORDER BY last_activity DESC
```

**EDITED:**

```
SELECT username, 
       GREATEST(
           IFNULL(date_created, 0), 
           IFNULL(last_login, 0), 
           IFNULL(last_updated, 0) 
       last_activity
FROM your_table
ORDER BY last_activity DESC
```

**EDITED AGAIN:**
On your db copy (having 27.451 records) I used:

```
SELECT id, 
       GREATEST(
           IFNULL(current_login_datetime, 0), 
           IFNULL(created_datetime, 0), 
           IFNULL(updated_datetime, 0)) 
       last_activity
FROM users
ORDER BY last_activity DESC
```

obtaining exaclty 27.451 records!!
To prove, run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT id, 
       GREATEST(
           IFNULL(current_login_datetime, 0), 
           IFNULL(created_datetime, 0), 
           IFNULL(updated_datetime, 0)) 
       last_activity
FROM users
ORDER BY last_activity DESC) der
```

and check that number returned is the same as the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
```

Your problem could be derived from a limit in total returned or showed records.
For example using Navicat light you can have 1000 records (but you can read 27.451 as total).

Comment: This looked to work at first, but it only found values for like 1/10 of the rows.  When I replaced 'GREATEST' with 'LEAST' it had like 1/5 of the rows.  I'm trying to diagnosis the problem but I'm not having much luck.

Comment: When I delete a few columns it increases the # of rows with data.  Maybe include some form of an OR operator?

Comment: @Ryan Grush: I've never heard about this behaviour :(

Comment: @Ryan Grush: how many records do you have in your table? Do you set some limit into MySql configuration file? Do you have some limit in your server?

Comment: So I'm not the biggest techie if you couldn't tell.  This is a copy of my DB on my localhost.  There is no limit as far as I know, I'll look into it though.  Once again, the # of rows increase with the less columns there are so I don't think thats the problem.

Comment: @Ryan Grush: how big is your db? Can you export to a .sql file and send it to me compressed (zip, rar or 7z)?

Comment: That definitely help clean things up a bit but it still not including rows.  Ex: our records go back to 2005, the latest in that edited query go back to 2006.  Once again when I delete columns to include in the query the results increase.  Its weird

Comment: Let me strip away some sensitive data and I'll gladly send it to you.

Comment: @Ryan Grush: my email is marco.giacinti @ gmail.com

Comment: @Ryan Grush: problem solved (on my pc). Would you reward me in some way? :) I'm joking :)

Comment: no problem, I'll buy you some lunch ... whats ur paypal address?

Comment: @Ryan Grush: I think accepting my answer is enough at the moment :D

Comment: Ahh I see where the problem was ... I forgot that we purged our DB a while back and deleted some inactive users.  This explains why all of the latest records go back to Sept 2006 but some of the created_datetime goes back to Nov 2005.  I knew that couldn't be a coincidence ... Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: and seriously I won't mind if you take me up on that lunch ;)

Comment: @Ryan Grush: I'm really really glad you solved your problem!! For the lunch, well... living in Italy I think that could be difficult, but nobody knows what future brings to us :D

Comment: Lol I just meant I'd give you some money for the help.  Either way I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Ryan Grush: no, nobody here asks money to help mates!! We help someone and we get helped when we're in the need. That's all, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If the values can be null and you want to select the first non `null` value use COALESCE. `GREATEST` and `LEAST` are also options

```
SELECT 
  username
  ,COALESCE(last_updated,last_login,date_created) AS not_null
  ,GREATEST(date_created, last_login, last_updated) AS latest
  ,LEAST(date_created, last_login, last_updated) AS first
FROM table1
ORDER BY last_activity DESC
```

If you want more control, you can use a CASE WHEN statement:

```
SELECT
  username
  , CASE WHEN date_created > '2011-01-31' THEN date_created
         WHEN last_login > '2011-01-31' THEN last_login
         ELSE last_updated END as its_complicated
.....
```

If you want the lastest AND you have `null` values floating around, use this query:

```
SELECT 
  username
  ,GREATEST(IFNULL(date_created,0), IFNULL(last_login,0), IFNULL(last_updated,0)) AS latest
FROM table1
ORDER BY last_activity DESC
```

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I'm working with http://imageshack.us/f/851/screenshot20110926at424.png/  The COALESCE operator was a slight improvement, but even though the not_null column has data for every row it has dates that aren't the latest.